# How Do I Remove last '[]' from a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, substring

I have some auto-generated text that includes substrings inside '[]'.

For example:

```
data[0]['x'][1]['y']
```

I want to get rid of the last sub-string.

Output:

```
data[0]['x'][1]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like RegEx could be useful here

Comment: does the input always has the given form? no text after last `[]` ?

Comment: @elmes: yes there won't be any other text after last []

Comment: @SreekeshOkky then the answer by Strille is great

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Are you writing your own language parser in Javascript? If not, I'd be willing to bet there's a simpler way to achieve whatever it is you're doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var result = input.replace( /\[[^\]]*\]$/, '' )
```

Will do the trick

Comment: To make it accept string like this the regexp will grow twice in size, and don't remebemer any circumates when i need this. (Only if varible names are made by catOnKeyboard)

Answer (score 3):

If it's auto-generated it sounds like it will always have the same form. In that case, you could simply cut the string at the last occurrence of "["

```
var str = "data[0]['x'][1]['y']";
str = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("["));
```